# Resteasy 404 error when deployed to AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, resteasy

When I run an app locally I have no problem accessing a rest resource using GET localhost:8080/resources/sqlData/projects, but for some reason when I try it on my AWS server, I get a 404 error using my-app.elasticbeanstalk.com/resources/sqlData/projects.

Does Amazon Web Services need a certain version of Resteasy or something? Here are my logs:

172.31.2.30 (70.114.214.76, 172.31.2.30) - - [24/Nov/2014:00:12:28 +0000] "GET /images/server.png HTTP/1.1" 200 662 "my-app.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MDDCJS)"
172.31.2.30 (70.114.214.76, 172.31.2.30) - - [24/Nov/2014:00:12:28 +0000] "GET /images/database.png HTTP/1.1" 200 753 "my-app.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MDDCJS)"
172.31.20.210 (70.114.214.76, 172.31.20.210) - - [24/Nov/2014:00:14:18 +0000] "GET /resources/sqlData/projects HTTP/1.1" 404 1003 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
172.31.20.210 (70.114.214.76, 172.31.20.210) - - [24/Nov/2014:00:15:32 +0000] "GET /resources/sqlData/projects HTTP/1.1" 404 1003 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"

Any ideas?

Comment: It probably means that your app has not been deployed correctly. The access log you posted is not very useful. Under Elastic BeansTalk console, you can collect all relevant logs. This will include the app deployment log and the Apache error log. Relevant error messages are likely to be there.

Comment: Thanks, but the rest of the logs seem to indicate that there weren't any other issues. I can navigate to my-app.elasticbeanstalk.com and the page displays correctly, so doesn't that mean that it was deployed correctly? The only issue I find is that the rest calls get a 404 error. I see " Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 1 completed." and "Command CMD-AppDeploy succeeded"  What other information should I look for on the logs?

Comment: There must be an error somewhere ... did you deploy the dependencies correctly ?  has your application access to the database ?  To help to debug, you can configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a public key on the instance, this will allow you to SSH in and to browse (tail, grep etc ) the logs live on the instance

Comment: How can I deploy the dependencies correctly? I just put them in the pom.xml file. I am able to access the AWS mySQL database I set up, so it seems my aws and mysql dependencies are working. I'll try SSH and see if that helps me pinpoint the issue. Thanks! I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found out what was causing the problem. I was setting the the jvm to v. 1.8, but I guess I needed it set to v. 1.7 for AWS. Anyways, I changed the following plugin in my pom.xml to 1.7 and Rest suddenly worked as expected.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source><!-- changed from 1.8 -->
                    <target>1.7</target><!-- changed from 1.8 -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```